# How to extract Bitmap image from SQL records?

Tags: image, databaselink, sql

[image]

I'm trying to extract image from records of the MSSQL demo database `NorthWind` with this codes,

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
conn = OpenSQLConnection["Northwind"];(*Northwind built mannually*)
imgdata = 
 Last@First@SQLExecute[conn, "select top 1 * from categories"];
```

and

```
ExportString[FromCharacterCode[First@imgdata], "RawBitmap", 
 ImageSize -> {60, 30}]
```

but it doesnot work properly, nor

```
file = "c:\\test.bmp";
BinaryWrite[file, FromCharacterCode@First@imgdata];
Close@file;
```

How to get the image exactly? Thanks!
`Northwind` database could be downloaded from Microsoft web site
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23654.
Also the testing `imgdata` mentioned up could be found here.

```
URLDownload["https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaYzO.png", "C:\\test.zip"];
ExtractArchive["C:\\test.zip", "C:\\"];
imgdata = Import["C:\\imgdata.txt"]//ToExpression
```

[image]

Comment: What is the database schema? e.g. what columns does the table have and what kind of values are in those columns.

Comment: The `imgdata` that Selected from records of the `Northwind` table `Categories`  and hidden in birds picture  is a sample for testing.

Comment: That description makes no sense to me. I expected a description such as "there is one column r which is the row number, one column c which is the column number, one column v which is the value of the corresponding pixel." Something that would allow us to map the database table to an image.

Comment: The `select` statement's screen snapshot is uploaded for your reference. thanks!

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for the update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Summary

The Northwind database was originally an MS Access database, so the pictures are BMP images wrapped within OLE objects.  We must strip the OLE header before parsing them.  The following function will perform that operation upon a `SQLBinary` column:

```
fromOleBmp[SQLBinary[data_]] := data[[79;;]] // ByteArray // ImportByteArray[#, "BMP"]&
```

These details are very specific to the images in the Northwind database.  However, the principle is generally the same for images in other databases.  Namely, if the image format is supported by *Mathematica* then `ImportByteArray` is the tool for the conversion.

For older versions of *Mathematica*, see the compatibility note at the bottom of this posting.

## Details

Let's start by loading all rows from the *Categories* table:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

$sql = OpenSQLConnection["Northwind"];

$data = SQLExecute[$sql, "SELECT * FROM Categories"];

Length[$data]

(* 8 *)
```

Here is the first row:

```
$data // First // InputForm // Shallow

(* {1, "Beverages", "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales", SQLBinary[<<1>>]} *)
```

... and here is the first *Picture* value:

```
$data[[1, 4]] // Short

(* SQLBinary[{21,28,47,0,2,0,0,0,13,0,14,0,20,0,33,0,255,255,255,255,66,
              105,116,<<10700>>,53,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,199,173,5,254}] *)
```

The Northwind database was originally an MS Access database.  So we might guess that the pictures are in BMP format.  Alas, it is not so simple:

```
$firstPicture = $data[[1, 4, 1]];

ImportByteArray[$firstPicture // ByteArray, "BMP"]

(* Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as BMP format. *)
```

It turns out that the images in Access databases were all [wrapped within OLE Objects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pranab/2008/07/15/removing-ole-header-from-images-stored-in-ms-access-db-as-ole-object/).  For BMP images, that header is 78 bytes long.  We can see the BMP file signature bytes "BM" at the appropriate position:

```
$firstPicture[[79 ;; 80]] // FromCharacterCode

(* "BM" *)
```

The bytes from that point forward constitute a valid, if low-quality, BMP:

```
ImportByteArray[$firstPicture[[79 ;;]] // ByteArray, "BMP"]
```

[image: gotta love those old low-res BMPs]

We will make a helper function for this conversion:

```
fromOleBmp[SQLBinary[data_]] := data[[79;;]] // ByteArray // ImportByteArray[#, "BMP"]&
```

... and then apply it to the 4th (*Picture*) column in the original data:

```
$converted = $data // Query[All, {4 -> fromOleBmp}];

$converted // Dataset
```

[image: Northwind Categories Table Dataset]

### Compatibility Note

In older versions of *Mathematica* which lack the function `ImportByteArray`, we can convert the BMP bytes using `ImportString` instead:

```
ImportString[$firstPicture[[79 ;;]] // FromCharacterCode, "BMP"]
```

The byte array approach is preferable if possible as arbitrary strings of bytes are not guaranteed to be preserved when converted into Unicode strings (although in practice they usually are in older versions).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @WReach's help,

```
fromOleBmp[SQLBinary[data_]] := data[[79;;]] // ByteArray // ImportByteArray[#, "BMP"]&

ImportString[$firstPicture[[79 ;;]] // FromCharacterCode, "BMP"]
```

then the last demo `imgdata` :

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

URLDownload["https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaYzO.png", "C:\\test.zip"];
ExtractArchive["C:\\test.zip", "C:\\"];
imgdata = Import["C:\\imgdata.txt"]//ToExpression(*from string to expression*);
```

could be shown indeed.

```
fromOleBmp[imgdata]
```

or

```
ImportString[(Last@imgdata)[[79 ;;]] // FromCharacterCode, "BMP"]
```

[image]